# Totalizing a complex in triagulated category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, triangulated-categories

I am self-studying homotopy theory and trying to understand a proof in [this paper](http://www.ltcc.ac.uk/media/london-taught-course-centre/documents/LTCC-notes-Lecture3-2019.pdf) on page 218

[image]

Let

$$ ... \to X_n \xrightarrow{{f_n}} X_{n-1} \xrightarrow{{f_{n-1}}}
 ... \xrightarrow{{f_2}} X_1 \to 0$$

be a sequence in trianguated category $\mathcal{I}$.

(sequence or more conventionally a complex means $f_{i+1} \circ f_i=0$).

Complete $X_2 \xrightarrow{{f_2}} X_1$ to a triangle

$X_2 \xrightarrow{{f_2}}  X_1 \xrightarrow{{f_y}} Y_1 
\xrightarrow{{f_{s2}}} \Sigma X_2 $.

Then the text says "
Because the composite
$X_3 \xrightarrow{{f_3}} X_2 \xrightarrow{{f_2}} X_1$ is zero,
we can lift to
$\Sigma X_3 \to Y_1$".

I don't understand why it's possible to make this lift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that exact triangles have the property that each morphism is a weak kernel/weak cokernel for the following/previous morphism in the following precise sense.

> **Lemma** In a (pre-)triangulated category, if
> $$ \newcommand\toby\xrightarrow
> X\toby{f} Y \toby{g} Z\toby{h} \Sigma X$$
> is an exact triangle, and $k:A\to Y$ is such that $gk=0$, then there exists a (not unique!) map $\tilde{k}:A\to X$ such that $k=f\tilde{k}$, and dually, if $l:Y\to A$ is such that $lf=0$, then there exists a map $\tilde{l}:Z\to A$ such that $l=\tilde{l}g$.

*Proof.*

Apply the morphism axiom to the following diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>1_A>> A @>>> 0 @>>>\Sigma A\\
@. @VkVV @V0VV @. \\
X @>f>> Y @>g>> Z @>h>> \Sigma X\\
\end{CD}
$$
$\blacksquare$

Now, how this gets applied to your question.
We have $f_2f_3=0$, and we have an exact triangle
$$\Sigma^{-1}Y_1 \to X_2 \toby{f_2} X_1\to Y_1,$$
so we can apply the lemma to make the lift.

Comment: I see, by the Lemma we get $f: X_3 \to \Sigma^{-1}Y_1$ and the lift we are looking for is $\Sigma f$. Thank you for your very apparent explanation!

Comment: @PlushkinNeponemaet Yep, exactly!